# Add to dict that's an attribute of a class

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I have a class like this:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, id, names):
        self.id = id
        self.names = names
```

Later on, I'm doing this:

```
classlist = []
classlist.append(MyClass("1", {"Key1", "Value"})) #add first key-value pair
classlist[0].names["Key2"] = "New Value" #add second key-value pair
```

but it fails on the third line with
`TypeError: 'set' object does not support item assignment`.
I'm new to Python, please teach me how to do this correctly.

Comment: "Attribute of a class" means something pretty specific in python; and your code doesn't have that.  For it to be a class attribute, it would be present on `MyClass.names`, but you have it set in the `__init__()` method, on `self`.  We would normally call this "Attribute of an instance".  Hope that helps clear up some confusion (that's unrelated to your actual question)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are passing in a set, not a dictionary.  It should be

```
classlist.append(MyClass("1", {"Key1": "Value"}))
```

Notice the `:` instead of `,` separating the Key1 and Value.  `{arg, arg, arg}` is shorthand for creating a set.

Comment: Now I feel really dumb. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @PeterW. It's an easy mistake to make.  No need to feel dumb.  But, the answer was in the error.  Python's built-in exceptions are usually pretty good about pointing out the mistake.

Comment: In the cases the error message doesn't seem helpful, it's nearly always due to a missing bracket

Answer (score 0):

you should use ":" for dictionary!!